# Better way of getting RTK result in getServerSideProps

Tags: typescript, next.js, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I'm using RTK Query to call an API in my `getServerSideProps` function. I can get the result within the function using the code below, but it feels kind of awkward. Also, the result is not typed, which would be preferable.

```js
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = wrapper.getServerSideProps(
  (store) => async (context: GetServerSidePropsContext) => {
    await store.dispatch(apiCall.initiate({ ...someParams }))
    await Promise.all(api.util.getRunningOperationPromises())

    const mutations = store.getState().api.mutations;
    const mutation = Object.values(mutations).find((m) => m?.endpointName === 'apiCall')
    //   |________| -> type is `unknown`
    
    if (mutation?.error) {
      const error = mutation.error as {
        status: number
        data: {
          error: string
        }
      }
    }

    return {
      props: {},
    }
  },
)
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that you want to call a mutation on SSR?
A mutation is meant to change something on the database - that should usually occur on user interaction, not on page render. For that you should always use a query!

Apart from that, you can do one of these two to get that api state:

```js
// for a query:
const queryResult = api.endpoints.apiCall.select(arguments)(getState())

// for a mutation you need to know the requestId
const runningMutation = dispatch(api.endpoints.apiCall.initiate(arguments))
const mutationResult = api.endpoints.apiCall.select({ requestId: runningMutation.requestId })(getState())
```

That said, you probably won't have a lot of reason to do this - there is no good reason to pass that data as props into your component - the component can just call `useApiCallQuery(arguments)` and get the results for the query that was done on the server - that's how it's meant to be used.

Comment: Thanks, will try this out. I'm using SSR to check and redirect if a given session is invalid (complete, expired, etc). If it is valid, then I'm updating the DB with a new session status and then posting a message to an external websocket connection, that's the reason behind this mutation/POST

Comment: I'm a bit unsure how to call the `select` function with my arguments (in my case `{ sessionId }`). Typescript allows `{ requestId: string | { requestId: string | undefined; fixedCacheKey: string | undefined } | SkipToken }`.

Comment: Ah yeah, for mutations you have to use the `requestId`. I'll add a bit more to the example